# In case of a lost passport, when getting a new one do you have to inform your country about all the visas you had on the lost passport?

Tags: visas, paperwork, passport-renewals, lost-documents

Let's say you are an international student from India studying in the USA and you lost your passport. You had Chinese, Russian, German, and of course, the US student visa on the lost passport. 
You only need the US visa on your new passport, so does the consulate/embassy dig up your "visa history" when issuing the new passport?

Comment: Consulates can't generally issue visas for other countries. If you lose a passport with a visa you will need to apply to your own consulate for a new passport and apply separately to the immigration service or consulate of the other country for a new visa.

Answer (score 8):

They don't dig up your visa history, nor can they issue foreign visas.

Next time you travel abroad, you will have to apply for a new visa at the US embassy/consulate before going back, providing your I-20 and explaining that you lost your old passport.

Answer (score 2):

The steps are as follows:

1. File a police report for your lost passport.
2. Take this police report to your country of nationality (or the country that issued the passport if you are dual national). They will generally give you a replacement document. This may either be a normal passport, an emergency travel document, or a special travel passport that allows you entry into the home country.

Now, as you are in the US - your I-94 and I-20 prove your legitimate entry; and on exit there are no immigration formalities - so you are safe there.

On return you'll have to re-apply for your visas and explain that your passport was reported lost (this is where the police report comes in handy). You may then have to provide additional documents and be granted a new stamp on your passport.

The validity will probably remain the same as your old visa - so make sure your current passport meets the requirements for the visas you are trying to re-apply for.

In other words, if your old passport was valid till 2020 and you new one is temporary and only valid till March 2018; if a visa was valid till May 2018 it probably won't get stamped onto your replacement passport.